# QueryDict serialization in Django 1.8

Tags: django, session-variables

We are having an issue with QueryDict serialization, one system is Linux the other one is Windows.

```
dict2 = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', }
qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
qdict.update(dict2)
print qdict
request.session['lal'] = qdict

#and then in another view I do:
print request.session['lal']
```

This outputs:

```
Linux:
<QueryDict: {u'a': ['one'], u'b': ['two']}>
{u'a': u'one', u'b': u'two'}
Windows:
<QueryDict: {u'a': ['one'], u'b': ['two']}>
{u'a': [u'one'], u'b': [u'two']}
```

Why the difference?

Windows:

```
Django==1.8
django-ckeditor==4.4.8
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-enumfield==1.2.1
django-phonenumber-field==0.7.2
django-social-auth==0.7.28
easy-thumbnails==2.2
httplib2==0.9.1
oauth2==1.5.211
oauthlib==0.7.2
phonenumbers==7.0.4
Pillow==2.8.1
psycopg2==2.6
PyJWT==1.1.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-slugify==1.0.2
python-social-auth==0.2.9
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
six==1.9.0
Unidecode==0.4.17
```

Linux:

```
Django==1.8
django-ckeditor==4.4.8
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-enumfield==1.2.1
django-phonenumber-field==0.7.2
django-social-auth==0.7.28
easy-thumbnails==2.2
httplib2==0.9.1
oauth2==1.5.211
oauthlib==0.7.2
phonenumbers==7.0.4
Pillow==2.8.1
psycopg2==2.6
PyJWT==1.1.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-slugify==1.0.2
python-social-auth==0.2.9
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
six==1.9.0
Unidecode==0.4.17
```

And SO complains that I have a lot of code because I put pips in code tags so I have to write some text, thank you for reading this